# Canonical map from fundamental group to Fuchsian group?

Tags: surfaces, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose we have a Riemann Surface $S$ of constant negative curvature $-1$. What is the canonical map from the fundamental group $\pi_1(S)$ to the discrete subgroup $\Delta \subset PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathbb{H}^2/\Delta \cong S$?

I'm struggling to see a connection between the two groups.

I think I'm probably missing some important facts here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The important fact you're missing is called the [uniformization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem), which says in this case that the hyperbolic plane is the universal cover of $S$.

Comment: So the uniformization theorem is telling me that there exists this discrete subgroup $\Delta$ such that the surface $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^2/\Delta$. But why is that group isomorphic to $\pi_1(S)$? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: @james: any space with a universal cover is the quotient of its universal cover by its fundamental group, acting as deck transformations. In this particular case, the fundamental group moreover acts as hyperbolic isometries.

Comment: Yes, after your comment I guessed we would have something like $S$ is isomorphic to (Universal cover of $S$)/($\pi_1(S)$) but I was not aware of how $\pi_1(S)$ would act on the universal cover. I am unfamiliar with deck transformations.

Comment: @james: this is standard material from a first course in algebraic topology; you can consult, for example, Hatcher for the details.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help!